# Discrete probability distribution of the number of loaded coin tosses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a loaded coin with `P[tails]=0.3`. I threw the coin `x times` and I know that there were exactly `300 heads`. The coin landed `x - 300 times on tails`. I forgot how many times I threw the coin and how many tails I saw.

I would like a function F(k) that tells me the probability that x = k.

(I tried to use the binomial distribution with varying number of trials but I am not sure if this is correct.)

Comment: Did you throw until the $300$th head appeared? If not, then what made you stop after $x$ throws?

Comment: I rolled a number between 0 and infinity to determine x.

Comment: I don't think the situation is well defined.  You know what $x$ was, it's not a matter of probability.  If, say, you imagined that some unseen person did this without disclosing the value of $x$ then as far as I can see you need some prior for the distribution of $x$.

Comment: Yeah we can assume I forgot what x and the number of tails was. What do you mean by prior?

Comment: Would an upper bound for x help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you stopped when you first saw the $300$th head.

- then the distribution for the number of tails has a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) $P(T=t)={t+299 \choose 299}0.3^{300} 0.7^t$ when $t \ge 0$ with mean  $700$ and variance $\frac{7000}{3}$
- and so the distribution for the number of tosses has  $P(X=x)={x-1 \choose 299}0.3^{300} 0.7^{x-300}$ when $x \ge 300$ with mean  $1000$ and variance $\frac{7000}{3}$

If you stopped for some other reason, you could use conditional probability to take that into account.  Unfortunately it is not physically possible to have a uniform distribution saying *"I rolled a number between $0$ and infinity to determine $x$"*, though you could assume this as an improper prior for Bayesian methods; in this particular case it would make a minimal difference

Comment: Would giving an upper limit for x help?

Comment: This actually was what I was looking for.

Comment: @eclipse An upper limit for $x$ would complicate the calculations, but not intolerably so